# Sub-components in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 I have a component that is clearly a sub-component to another component.  For instance, a `Contact` component within a `ContactsPage` component.  Since the introduction of modules, I must now add `ContactComponent` to the `declaration`-section of my NgModule, making the `Contact` component available in all HTML templates in the module.  This gives me two problems:

1. The component hierarchy tree is flattened into a list which makes the project structure harder to follow
2. The namespace is also flattened, I'd rather get an error if i accidentally reference `<contact>` outside `ContactsPage`. I also would like to create very local subcomponents such as `<entry>` without having to worry about name clashes elsewhere in my app.

Is there no way of making a sub-component available only within a specific component?  Alternatively, should I make turn every component with sub-components into a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `Contact` and `ContactsPage` to a `ContactsModule` NgModule, and then add this module to `imports` of modules where you want to use `ContactsPage`